# How to get access to the partial derivatives of output with respect to inputs in deep learning model?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, automatic-differentiation

I want to create my own loss function in keras, which contains derivatives. For example,

```
def my_loss(x):
    def y_loss(y_true,y_pred):
        res = K.gradients(y_pred,x)
        return res
    return y_loss
```

is defined, and

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model_loss = my_loss(x=model.input)
model.compile(loss=model_loss, optimizer='adam')
```

Now because the input is of two-dimensional,

```
K.gradients(y_pred,x)
```

must be a two-dimensional vector.
However, I don't know how to get each scalars in the gradients. What I finally want is all the second derivatives of y_pred with respect to x. Is there a convenient way to get this?

---

It is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935778/second-derivative-in-keras) post, but this post separated two-dimensional variables into two one-dimensional variables. Is there any other way to get gradients without separating inputs?

Comment: Sorry if I am missunderstanding, what you are trying to achieve, but typically you want to calculate the gradient of the loss with respect to something and not of the output?! Anyway, I think your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935778/second-derivative-in-keras) post

Comment: @pafi Yes it is similar. But your reference separated two inputs using function API, while I try to differentiate with respect to a vector element.

Comment: Yea, the core concepts are the same. But I think these answers will help you as well.

Comment: Bit unclear what you are asking; Do you want to calculate the Laplacian of a Neural Network with respect to inputs? Or do you want the loss function to be something related to the Laplacian. If you just need to calculate the Laplacian; there is no need to add it as a loss function. Some clarification would help us answer

Comment: @Abhimanyu At first, it was a Laplacian, so maybe tf.linalg.trace(tf.hessians) resolves the problem, but now I want to get access to each partial derivatives. Sorry for make you confused. I editted the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Keras does not have a convenient way to get each components of the gradients. Therefore, I used tensorflow to resolved this problem.

if f if the object function with variable x=(x1,x2)

```
X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(None,2))
f=f(X)#assume it is defined'
```

then df/dx_1 is

```
tf.gradients(f,x)[0][:,0]
```

df/dx_2 is

```
tf.gradients(f,x)[0][:,1]
```

d^2f/dx_1^2 is

```
tf.gradietns(tf.gradients(f,x))[0][:,0]
```

d^2f/dx_2^2 is

```
tf.gradietns(tf.gradients(f,x))[0][:,1]
```

d^2f/dx_1dx_2 is

```
tf.gradietns(tf.gradients(f,x)[0][:,0])[0][:,1]
```

I believe there is a better way, but I can't find.

Answer (score 1):

If you want Laplacians , why not use tf.hessians which has all second derivates? The Laplacian should equal the trace of the Hessian Matrix (by identity)

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/hessians

Comment: A problem arise when I access the values of each element of the Hessian Matrix. I want the values for tf.hessians(y_pred,x) but this offers only a Tensor type stuff. Can you tell me how to access this?