# Keras doesn't train with derivative in custom loss

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I'm trying to approximate the sine function using a neural network (Keras) and with data and the fact `d/dx d/dx sin(x) = -sin(x)`. This property of the sine function is used in the custom loss function of the neural network.

My code currently looks like this

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow import keras
from numpy import random

# --- Disable eager execution
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

# --- Settings
x_min = 0
x_max = 2*np.pi

n_train = 64
n_test = 64

# --- Generate dataset
x_train = random.uniform(x_min, x_max, n_train)
y_train = np.sin(x_train)

x_test = random.uniform(x_min, x_max, n_test)
y_test = np.sin(x_test)

# --- Create model
model = keras.Sequential()

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="tanh", input_dim=1))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="tanh"))

model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="tanh"))

def grad(input_tensor, output_tensor):
    return keras.layers.Lambda( lambda z: keras.backend.gradients( z[ 0 ], z[ 1 ] ), output_shape = [1] )( [ output_tensor, input_tensor ] )

def custom_loss_wrapper(input_tensor, output_tensor):

    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        mse_loss = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred)
        derivative_loss = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(input_tensor, -grad(input_tensor, grad(input_tensor, output_tensor))[0])
        return mse_loss + derivative_loss

    return custom_loss

# --- Configure learning process
model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.01),
        loss=custom_loss_wrapper(model.input, model.output),
        metrics=['MeanSquaredError'])

# --- Train from dataset
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=1000, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

# --- Evaluate model
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Especially important is the custom loss function. The Lambda-Definition of the derivative comes from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49935778/second-derivative-in-keras). Sadly it seems like the model doesn't train correctly. The loss approaches zero and stays above 10.

Without the derivative term the network works fine, but I can't seem to find the mistake in the derivative calculation. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

As for your model, you can try to do hyperparameters tuning,

- **Setting the learning rate to a lower value**
- **Increase the epoch**
- **Add more training dataset.**

You can also add **more layers**, add **dropouts** for overfitting and try different **activation functions** and **optimization methods**.
By doing all this, you will be able to get a **good model performance**.

Comment: So you say that the loss function works correctly and I just need to tune the hyperparamters?